# click "all sheets" in Google Sheets using Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'd eventually like to write an extension that can click on "all sheets" in Google Sheets and select a given sheet. For right now I'm testing in the console (not sure if that detail matters).

I've tried:

```
temp = document.getElementsByClassName("docs-sheet-all")
el = temp[0]
el.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown'));
el.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseup'));
```

the above code does nothing. My goal is to click on "all sheets" then select a sheet.

Looking at the event listener it looks like there is a mousedown and mouseover (and mouseout) listener on a div which contains both adding a new sheet and selecting the all sheets icon - but not on the "all sheets" div. There is also a mousedown listener (actually multiple) on the document itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need the [`bubbles: true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/bubbles) option:

```
var el = document.querySelector('.docs-sheet-all');
el.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown', { bubbles: true }));
el.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseup', { bubbles: true }));
```

Comment: I spent that long to have it be a problem with bubbling asdfasdfasdfsadfds. I thought bubbling was true by default. I guess perhaps that's only for actual mouse clicks. Thanks!